# Why use の instead of が?

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-が

I know that の can be used instead of が when modifying a noun like in these examples:

1. 日本語のわかる人
2. 私のできる日本語

But in these cases:

> 健康のためにあるいはリクリエーションのためにという**スポーツのある**一方で、スポーツが仕事というプロスポーツも存在している。

> 頂点に通じる長い山道のどこを歩いているのか**の違いであり**、険しさや空気の薄さは上に行くほどつらくはなるが、歩いて進むことや歩き方には変わりはない。

Why is の used here in the parts in bold？ Isn't it supposed to be が? I get the meaning but don't understand the grammar here.

Comment: Case one is like the example you already understand. 一方 is a noun. Case two is totally different. There is no verb so I'm not sure why you expect to see が. 違い is a noun and it's being modified by the preceding question using の.

Comment: @user3856370: [Comments are not for answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).

Answer (score 1):

As you say の can replace が as a subject marker.

For the first sentence, just as in 1 and 2 in the question, の/が are (to an extent) interchangeable: スポーツのある/スポーツがある are both fine.

In the second one, using が is most probably possible and won't change meaning much. But grammatically, as noted in the comment, they are different:

The sentence as is has an implicit subject which should be what is being discussed: (それは)...どこを歩いているのか**の**違いであり, which literally means *It is a matter **of** where you are walking...*.

On the other hand, using が would make *where you...* the subject (of である）: どこを歩いているか**が**違いである = *Where you are walking ... **is** the difference*. This is ok grammatically, but it sounds like emphasizing the difference and does not seem to fit the context (the emphasis should be 変わりはない).